# Parsing HTML with Erlang

Tags: erlang

I am trying to write my first Erlang application, and I need to parse HTML into some sort of internal format. I have had a look at the merl module, but as far as I can see it is only capable of parsing XML.

When I supply HTML to merl, it chokes on the non symetric tags.

Which library should I be using for this?

Answer (score 10):

Have just found [mochiweb_html](https://github.com/mochi/mochiweb/blob/master/src/mochiweb_html.erl). Looks like it does what I want...