# erlang or ADA -- create web Scraping - parse information from couple website and generate in html

Tags: parsing, erlang, ada, erlangweb

I must do some web for my elrang or ada project.
1)I must write: download concurrent data from three portals associated with weather --> It is a main problem. I don't know how to download such data. Maybe some parser ? I found some information about erlang parser but there are not enough to understand to me. May can be some parser for ada?

What exactly want to do:
I have got some web with html structure:

```
<div class="info">
        <span class="cond">Mostly clear and colder</span>
        <span class="low" style="color:#ffffff;">Lo </span><strong class="temp">-12<span>°</span></strong>
        </div>
```

And want to extract information: "-12". Is any possible to do it?

After extracted this informations must update my database 
Finally create some graph which illustrates all parsed informations.

Any hint will be very appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML with Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030977/parsing-html-with-erlang)

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9152174/113848).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a library like [Python's Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [Ruby's Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) for Erlang. I think your best bet is to use Beautiful Soup or Nokogiri and then write some code to transfer the relevant information from Python/Ruby to Erlang via the [BERT-RPC protocol](http://bert-rpc.org/).

I also did some searching and came across this: http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-January/049023.html Hope this helps!